# How do I connect to a SQL Server database from in one server from a Springboot app in another server?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, remote-access

How do I connect to a SQL Server database from in one server from a Springboot app in another server?

The SQL Server server is running windows. The Springboot app is on a Linux box.

I'm already able to make http calls and SSH into other machines, I now need to be able to run simple SQL commands on an SQL database on another machine.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "run simple SQL commands" Java, you use the [SQL Server JDBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).